# Why is this function within the $\Bbb{R^2}$ domain?

Tags: functions

From [curiosity](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=ouP9xNujkNo) I've seen the *physical* existance of the function:

## $$z=x·y$$

After going to [Wolfram Alpha site](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=z%3Dx%2ay) I've seen that function happens to belong to the $\Bbb{R^2}$ domain. However, including 3 variables for the 3 axis, why isn't it in the $\Bbb{R^3}$ domain?

Answer (score 1):

This can be written as $f(x,y)=x*y$. Here it follows that $f:R^2\to\ R$, where $R^2$ is the domain.

Comment: you meant $f:R^2\rightarrow R$ right? There is a typo.

Comment: Oh my yes! Thanks a lot